# Compartir filter pipe en el appcomponent

Tags: angular

Tengo un input search en mi appcomponent.html, y luego a través de  muestro mi home.component.html en el cual tengo un bucle for, hay alguna opción de escribir en mi input del appcomponent y que me filtre con un pipe el bucle que tengo en el appcomponent?

El pipe es el siguiente:

```
 transform(value: any, arg: any): any {
    const resultPost = [];
    for(const entrada of value){
      if (entrada.categoria.indexOf(arg) > - 1) {
        resultPost.push(entrada);
      };
    };
    return resultPost;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

A continuacion le agrego un ejemplo.

busca-categoria.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'buscaCategoria'
})
export class BuscaCategoriaPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {
     const resultPost = [];

    for(const entrada of value){
      if (entrada.indexOf(args) > - 1) {
        resultPost.push(entrada);
      };
    };
    return resultPost;
  }

}
```

App.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BuscaCategoriaPipe } from './busca-categoria.pipe';
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';
import { ListaComponent } from './lista/lista.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   AppComponent,
    BuscaCategoriaPipe,
    SearchComponent,
    ListaComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,   
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Search.Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  search: string = '';

  @Output() buscar = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onEnter(value: string) { 
    this.search = value; 
    this.buscar.emit(this.search);
  }

}
```

Search.Component.html

```
<input #box (keyup.enter)="onEnter(box.value)">
```

Lista.Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lista',
  templateUrl: './lista.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lista.component.scss']
})
export class ListaComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  @Input() filtro;

  words: string [] = [
    'firstName',
    'lastName',
    'addressLineOne',
    'addressLineTwo',
    'city',
    'country',
    'postalCode',
    'phone',
    'age',
    'email',
    'edit',
    'delete'
  ];

}
```

Lista.Component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of words | buscaCategoria: filtro">
    {{ item }}
 </div>
```

App.Component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'stackoverflow';
 filtro: string;

 Buscar(filtro){
   this.filtro = filtro;
 }
}
```

app.component.html

```
 <div>
  <!-- Press enter after typing the search work -->
  <app-search (buscar)="Buscar($event)"></app-search>
  <app-lista [filtro] = "filtro"></app-lista>      
</div>
```

Espero esto le ayude con su problema.

Comment: Mi problema es que no se hacerlo en dos componentes distintos

Comment: Ok, eso no me quedo claro en su pregunta, en unos minutos le agrego la solucion con diferentes componentes.

Comment: @MiguelÁngelMartín Acabo de editar la respuesta para que tenga 2 componentes diferentes que se comunican y hacen el filtrado.